# Data in not displayed on checkbox in C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to display the values from database. The textbox values are displayed successfully but checkbox values are not displayed, and it shows the error. I get the error shown in this screenshot:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97BXW.jpg)

My code:

```
sql = "select * from repair where repairid = '" + repairid + "'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

SqlDataReader dread;

con.Open();

dread = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dread.Read())
{
    checkBox7.CheckState = dread[6].ToString();
}
```

Comment: `CheckBox.CheckState` cannot be set to a `string`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Error message is pretty self explanatory. `ToString` returns a string. `checkBox7.CheckState` does not take a string.

Comment: then how i display the data on checkbox

Comment: @NisaYathu You'll need to determine how the data from the `repair` table will translate to a `CheckState`.  This means you will need to decide which state will show when the data is `true/false/null` (I assume)

Comment: I would also strongly advise looking into parameterized queries, and implementing proper `using` blocks for your database objects.  There are a ton of great guides online that can help you get started.

Comment: if you write the code it is big help for me

Comment: @NisaYathu one of the most underrated skills a good developer needs is the ability to search for existing solutions to a current problem.  I guarantee if you put your mind to it, you'll find a great starting point that you can modify to fit your needs.  I know you can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(dread[6].ToString = = "True")
{
    CheckBox7.Checked = "true";
}
else
{ 
    CheckBox7.Checked = "false";
}
```